# NUnit Unit tests not showing in Test Explorer with Test Adapter installed

Tags: nunit

I've installed NUnit Test Adapter for VS2012 + 2013.  When I first installed the Adapter tests were showing up, but they stopped showing up for some reason today.  After building, rebuilding, cleaning, restarting, nothing shows up in Test Explorer.  Why would this be happening?  I'm using VS2013 Ultimate.

Comment: Try right clicking on your test project and then click run. It'll populate the windows with the tests again.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell it doesn't.  I see the green bar in Test Explorer start to go and then stop a split second later.

Comment: Do you have any other test tools that could be interfering? I use R# to run my tests, and I'm using VS2012, so I don't your environment well enough. I do know that when I've closed the window, or run a small subset of tests, the full test tree disappears.

Comment: You could try unloading the test project, rebuilding, and then re-load it...

Comment: @ChaseFlorell I have R# but it's slow as molasses with NUnit tests... and it was working before which is frustrating.  I'll try unloading.

Comment: I did hear complaints about R# and VS2013, but I can't remember what for.

Comment: For me, I had an upgrade to Windows 10.  They didnt appear after upgrade.  I had to install NUnit 3 Test Adapter - I didnt see it in my list of Extensions when I restarted.  Cant quite remember having it installed previously but I guess I did - but all NUnit tests DID show up in Test Explorer prior to upgrade.   NOTE:  I am using VS2013 Ultimate.

Comment: Mixing frameworks (nunit, mstest, xunit) can also cause problems... don't do that

Comment: One time with MS test, it was because my test class wasn't public. Just saying...

Answer (score 89, accepted):

If your test project is set to target a 64bit platform, the tests won't show up in the NUnit Test Adapter.

Comment: It may be that it needs to match the architecture specified in the menu at Test -> Test Settings -> Default Processor Architecture

Comment: @Brannon It does. If that's set to x64, tests in x64 projects are visible.

Comment: Something way more stupid has happened here - forgot to add [Test] attribute to my test method :)

Comment: This problem appears to still be present in the NUnit 3 test adapter. See Simoyd's solution regarding test adapter architecture (x64 vs x86).

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. Note to others that you have to restart VS after changing the target platform for Test Explorer to find the unit tests.

Comment: This is an incorrect answer. To run the tests, select "Test" -> "Test Settings" -> "Default Processor Architecture" -> "x64"

Comment: In VS2022, you have to add a runsettings file to set the TargetPlatform

Answer (score 185):

If you're using a **NUnit3+ version**, there is a new Test Adapter available.

Go to "Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Online" and search for **"NUnit3 Test Adapter"** and then install.

Comment: Extra +1 because this also fixed the issue with Code Coverage metrics disappearing.

Comment: If the firewall proxy has blocked the url via Extensions and Updates then use this url to download the adapter. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NUnitDevelopers.NUnit3TestAdapter

Comment: Note that you may also need to disable the NUnit2 Test Adapter.

Comment: What's the difference between getting it this way and getting it from the NuGet package manager?

Comment: Using NuGet you'll have access to the api of nunit. Using this way you'll be able to run the tests on the Test Explorer (by default it runs only the MS Test).

Comment: nunit3 test adapter allows running tests but i haven't been able to ever stop a test. like when your test gets into an infinite loop and you already know it is wrong, i couldn't stop it.

Comment: @EakanGopalakrishnan Strange, but I've never saw a infinite loop inside of a unit test. I saw a dependency loop, but after a while I received a stackoverflow error.

Comment: yes @RicardoFrança . i do get a stackoverflow, but i have to wait till i get that. There should be an easier way to just stop what it is doing. 
Like if you had resharper you can stop a test in the middle.

Comment: @EakanGopalakrishnan There is a Cancel Button at the top left side of the Test Explorer window, try to use it. I've tested now with a loop and it worked.

Answer (score 57):

My test assembly is 64-bit. From the menu bar at the top of visual studio 2012, I was able to select 'Test' -> 'Test Settings' -> 'Default Processor Architecture' -> 'X64'. After a 'Rebuild Solution' from the 'Build' menu, I was able to see all of my tests in test explorer. Hopefully this helps someone else in the future =D.

Comment: Make sure you check the architecture of your assemblies and programs. Even though the platform for your solution or project might be explicitly set to x64, if your test architecture doesn't match, you will have trouble running tests.

Answer (score 30):

Check for NUnit versions mismatch. The currently available NUnit Test Adapter only works for NUnit version 2.6.4 and below. 
To downgrade NUnit from version 3.x go to
Package Manager Console > update-package NUnit -version 2.6.4

http://jeremybytes.blogspot.co.ke/2015/11/review-of-unit-testing-makes-me-faster.html

Comment: You sir, have solved my issue precisely! Thank you! Theres a nuget package called NUnitTestAdapter.WIthFramework that works a treat!

Comment: I had a similar problem with NUnit versions mismatch. Some (but not all) of my tests were not displaying in Test Explorer so I tried all kinds of recommendations such as updating the NUnit test adapter. I had previously upgraded NUnit from 3.6.1 to 3.7.1 but for some reason one of my projects was still referencing nunit.framework.dll version 3.6.1 while everything else was referencing 3.7.1. I updated the reference to 3.7.1 and this did the trick. So far my tests haven't disappeared. Fingers crossed!

Answer (score 26):

In my situation the 'NUnit3 Test Adapter' has been disabled.
To re-enable it go to menu

Tools->Extensions and Updates...

On the left side select 'Installed'->'All'.

On the upper right corner search for 'nunit'.

If you have 'NUnit3 Test Adapter' installed, with the found item you can enable/disable it.

[image]

Comment: For me this did not work. Tried uninstalling and it pretended to be gone but it was there after the restart. I figured out that I installed NUnit as a standard user and then tried uninstalling it as an Administrator. VS doesn't say anything about this... So the solution is try enabling it without administrator privileges or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks, this was the exact problem in my case

Answer (score 10):

This answer seems pretty basic but wasn't completely obvious to me at first. If you (re)build the solution it only builds the projects that are configured to build in the `Build -> Configuration Manager`

This was my issue, I must have inadvertently changed a build configuration settings or something that caused my test projects not to build (when they previously were). So the `Test Explorer` window was looking at dlls that were out of date. It became clear to me this was the case after doing a `Clean` and seeing most of my tests disappear and not come back after a `rebuild`...further inspection of `bin` folder showed that these projects weren't being built at all.

Comment: Although all projects were set to *build* in the configuration Manager I had to manually build each test project to make the tests show up again.

Comment: I manually built my test projects.  That wasn't enough.  I had to do what this answer said.

Answer (score 10):

I had a working setup (for NUnit2 and NUnit3 depending on the solution, and multiple versions of Visual Studio between 2012 and 2017), and it suddenly stopped working one day: no tests detected in any solution or version of VS.

In my case, it helped to delete `%localappdata%\Temp\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions`. After a restart of VS, everything worked as before.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using **VS 2017 and .net core** ,as said [here](http://www.alteridem.net/2017/05/04/test-net-core-nunit-vs2017/), you should add references to the test framework **NUnit 3.6.1**, to the test runner **NUnit3TestAdapter 3.8.0-alpha1** and to the test SDK **Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk 15.0.0**.

Comment: I'm not using .NET Core, but installing the NUnit test adapter when I moved to VS2017 solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 8):

1. Tools
2. NuGet Package Manager
3. Manage NuGet Packages For Solution
4. Browse
5. NUnitTestAdapter.WithFramework
6. Ctrl+R,A to build/run tests

[image]

Using NUnitTestAdapter.WithFramework makes sure there are little/no inconsistencies across versions of NUnit and NUnit Adapter (i.e. "it just works")

Comment: for me it starts working after update adapter to NUnitAdapter3 (VS Menu ->Tools->Extensions And Updates...) + update NuGet page for NUnit from 2.6.3 to 3.2.1 .Thanks!

Comment: this is the only thing that worked for me - had to be the "WithFramework" one (not just the standard adapter)

Answer (score 4):

Check whether you have stated 
[TestFixureSetUp]
and
[Test]

in the test class

sample:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
   public class SimpleCalculator
   {
      public Calculator _calculator;
      [TestFixtureSetUp]
      public void initialize()
      {
         _calculator = new Calculator();
      }
      [Test]
      public void DivideTest()
      {
         int a = 10;
         int b = 2;
         int expectedValue = a/b;
         int actualValue = _calculator.Divide(a, b);
         Assert.AreEqual(expectedValue, actualValue, "Functionality not working properly!");
      }
   }   
}
```

Comment: TestFixtureSetup seems to be obsolete, better is <NUnit.Framework.OneTimeSetUp>

Answer (score 1):

I had to uninstall then re-install the **xunit.runner.visualstudio** nuget package.  I tried this after trying all the above suggestions, so may be it was a mixture of things.

Answer (score 1):

One other cause to this problem is if you open a project from **a mapped drive** - Visual Studio handles such projects properly, but apparently Nunit doesn't support them.

Copying the project to a physical fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also found that when I uninstalled nunit v3.2.1, the nunit framework reference for v3.2.1 was still in my project in solution explorer.
Solution Explorer > *ProjectName* > References

If you right click it will show the version. Remove this
Then Right click on References > Add Reference.

Search for the version 2.x version and add then rebuild solution.

That worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the problem mentioned by op

My case was that I was handed an old project and the tests were actually part of the system under test. I assume they were using the external test runner.

this task chain resolved the issue for me

- created a test project,
- moved the test files there
- added references so the test project would compile
- added the Nunit and Nunit adapter  NuGet packages to the test project
- recompiled

i was able to successfully run the Nunit tests.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `TestCaseSource` attribute, ensure the source exists and respects [the documentation](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseSource-Attribute), otherwise your tests will not be discovered.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where the tests where not being discovered. I had the correct version of NUnit, versions matched up between NUnit and adapter, and the tests where tagged correctly. I was running VS 2017 Enterprise not as an administrator. After starting VS as administrator the tests appeared.

Answer (score 0):

I started a new solution with a test project in it, and compared it against my original, problem project. The original, for some reason, had an **app.config** in it. I excluded that file from the project and saw my tests reappear in the test explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too but the cause was different.  I'm using VS2017 with F# 4.0.

Firstly, the console in Visual Studio does not give you enough details why the tests could not be found; it will just fail to the load the DLL with the tests.  So use NUnit3console.exe on the command line as this gives you more details.

In my case, it was because the test adapter was looking for a newer version of the F# Core DLL (4.4.1.0) (F# 4.1) whereas I'm still using 4.4.0.0 (F# 4.0).  So I just added this to the app.config of the test project:-

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-65535.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="4.4.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

i.e. redirect to the earlier F# core.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, when suddenly any test didn't appeared on Test Explorer  window.
I has the updated version of "NUnit3TestAdapter"

and after lots of searches and efforts,
I found that I need set the following values in project properties:
[In Solution Explorer window: right click on Project > Properties]
Under Build tab, set Platform=x64, and set Platform target=x86 or Any CPU
Build the project and all tests will be appear on Test Explorer  window.

Important note:
I came to a solution after seeing the next msg in the output window:

"Test run will use DLL(s) built for framework Framework45 and platform X86. Following DLL(s) will not be part of run:  AutomationTests.dll is built for Framework Framework45 and Platform X64."

Answer (score 0):

I had some msbuild.exe processes that were hung. I don't know if that was my problem or not, but it took me a lot of trail and error with reinstalling various NUnit adaptors before I found the hung processes.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my $.02 here, I ran into a similar issue just yesterday, where 168 of my tests were missing.  I tried most everything in this post - most especially making sure my version(s) of NUnit were the same - all to no avail.  I then remembered that I had my tests divided into playlists; *and these **do not** update automatically as you add new tests*.  So, when I deleted the playlists, **BAM!**, all of my tests were back once more.

Answer (score 0):

I use NUnit 3 and tried most of the other solutions I saw here. None of those worked for me.

[image: NUnit tests missing in test explorer]

Even though already selected, reselecting the "Playlist: All Tests" option in test explorer showed all hidden tests in my case. I need to do this after every rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your test class is public. I often make this mistake then I just look at the code for 5 minutes what is going on.

[Test]
**public** void YourTest()
{
...
}

Answer (score 0):

1. Tools
2. NuGet Package Manager
3. Manage NuGet Packages For Solution
4. Browse
5. NUnit3TestAdapter (NUnit 3 in my case ..)
6. After installation it should be possible to use the default TestExplorer included with the installation of Visual Studio.

[image: NUnit3TestAdapter]

Answer (score 0):

If your test project is not x86, the tests will not be found until you tell the test runner the correct target platform.

Prior to Visual Studio 2022, this was the "Test/Test Settings/Default Processor Architecture" option.

In VS2022 you need to [create a 'runsettings' file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2022) and set the test project to use it. In that file you can specify the Target Platform, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RunSettings>
  <!-- Configurations that affect the Test Framework -->
  <RunConfiguration>
    <TargetPlatform>x64</TargetPlatform>
  </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
```

You still also need to include the Nunit3TestAdapter and Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk nugets (and make sure the project actually built, and check the various other more obscure mistakes mentioned in other answers)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your tests are properly marked with the Test attribute.  If all of the tests are marked with only the Explicit attribute, the TestAdapter doesn't recognize the fixture.