# SpecFlow test not displayed in the test explorer

Tags: visual-studio, specflow

I have installed Visual studio 2015 on multiple PC and application that is using SpecFlow. The application is working normally on 1 pc because everything there was installed long time ago. However on the other PCs tests are not being displayed in the test explorer, and I need them in the test explorer.
Please help

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30573482/built-tests-are-not-added-to-the-visual-studio-test-explorer-window) or installed the NUnit test adapater as suggested [here](http://www.marcusoft.net/2012/09/getting-visual-studio-2012-test.html), both links found from simply googling the quetion title...

Comment: you also should specify which testing framework you are generating your tests in, NUnit, MSTest, XUnit etc etc

Comment: The tests are in NUnit

Comment: Yes Sam I have tried suggested no results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys but I managed to fix my problem. The tests are displayed as soon as NUnit Test Adapter is installed:

Go to Tools->Extensions and updates ->Online->Visual Studio Gallery->Tools->Testing and select NUnit Test Adapter

Answer (score 4):

For me, the test displayed after the `Specflow MSTest` was added from NuGet.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Tests are not displayed in the Test Explorer window when using SpecFlow+ Runner**

I run into this all the time. There is a great section on the GitHub repo page for specflow that I keep bookmarked for when stuff like this comes up. Usually this one (deleting the cache file) fixes issues for me.

The Visual Studio Test Adapter cache may also get corrupted, causing tests to not be displayed. If this happens, try clearing your cache as follows:

1. Close all Visual Studio instances
2. Navigate to your %TEMP%\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions\ folder and delete any sub-folders related to SpecFlow/SpecRun.
3. Reopen your solution and ensure that it builds.

https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Troubleshooting-Visual-Studio-Integration

Hope this helps

Comment: No, it doesn't help. I've tried deleting VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensons and also reinstalling Specflow+runner, nothing solves the problem

Comment: closing visual studio instance, opening visual studio again and rebuilding the project solved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

if you have a file .srpofile in your solution, then adjust your gherkin steps according to file tags.#
\in my case .srprofile is like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestProfile xmlns="http://www.specflow.org/schemas/plus/TestProfile/1.5">
    <Settings projectName="project.test" projectId="{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}" outputFolder=".\Results" />
    <Execution stopAfterFailures="0" retryFor="None" testSchedulingMode="Sequential" />
    <Filter>@automated</Filter>
    <TestAssemblyPaths>
        <TestAssemblyPath>project.test.dll</TestAssemblyPath>
    </TestAssemblyPaths>
</TestProfile>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add these configurations in your `.csproj` file.

1. Remove `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` and replace it with `Microsoft.TestPlatform.TestHost`
2. Add these two in `PropertyGroup` tag and rebuild the project

   ```
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>false</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
    <GenerateRuntimeConfigDevFile>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigDevFile>
   ```