# How do I get SpecFlow tests to show up in Test Explorer

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2015, specflow

When I created a feature file, and ran generate test steps. Specflow runner created a Steps file.  When I built the solution however, the Test Explorer did not populate.

I am using VS2015

I have already tried all the remedies listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30573482/built-tests-are-not-added-to-the-visual-studio-test-explorer-window) to no avail.

Installed packages:

NUnit 3.7.1
NUnit.Console 3.6.1
NUnit.ConsoleRunner 3.6.1
NUnit3TestAdapter 3.7.0
SpecFlow 2.1.0
SpecFlow.NUnit 2.1.0
SpecFlow.NUnit.Runners 2.1.0

Comment: Do you use NUnit3 or 2.6.x?

Comment: Please add the version numbers to your installed packages

Comment: added version numbers.

Comment: Related post - [Built tests are not added to the Visual Studio Test Explorer window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30573482/465053)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install a visual studio extension called *Nunit 3 Test Adapter*. This is not a project nuget package but a visual studio extension to handle properly the generated tests by Specflow.

How-to: from the menu at the top select Tools -> On the sidebar in left select Online -> Enter the extension name and install it.

Possible restart of VisualStudio will be required.