# VB.NET nUnit TestFixture: test not found in Test Explorer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, selenium, nunit

Here is my problem.

I have created a new class in my unit test project and added the TestFixture attribute to the class.

I have then added the TestMethod and built the project. The problem is that Test Explorer does not find the test so I cannot run it!

```
<TestFixture()> _
Public Class _SmokeTests

<TestMethod()>
Public Sub ServiceIsAccessible()
Pages.BaseNavigation.GoToLoginPage()
Assert.IsTrue(Pages.loginPage.IsAtPage())
End Sub
```

If I change 'TestFixture' to 'TestClass' then the test is found, but this is not what I want as I believe I need 'TestFixture' to run the 'TestFixtureTearDown' methods etc.

I am using VS2013.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: perhaps you already have a class called TextFixture?

Comment: Have you installed either the NUnit Test Adapter or the NUnit 3 Test Adapter as an extension? Does the adapter you installed match the version of NUnit you are using in your project?

Comment: Test Class and TestMethod are MsTest attributes rather than NUnit. Sounds as if your tests are not referencing NUnit at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I have sorted the issue - it was a version mismatch.

As I am using NUnit (3.0) I needed to install NUnit3 Test Adapter.

[NUnit Unit tests not showing in Test Explorer with Test Adapter is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298347/nunit-unit-tests-not-showing-in-test-explorer-with-test-adapter-is-installed)

Thanks everyone for your time.