# In the latest release SpecFlow menu items "Run SpecFlow Scenario" and "Debug SpecFlow Scenario" are removed

Tags: specflow

https://specflow.org/2019/changes-to-the-specflow-visual-studio-extension/

How to start debug now in VS2015?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When compiling scripts, SpecFlow generates unit tests. You need to debug them. The breakpoints on the script file will work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Test Explorer integrated in Visual Studio (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/run-unit-tests-with-test-explorer?view=vs-2019)

Comment: I use NUnit - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298347/nunit-unit-tests-not-showing-in-test-explorer-with-test-adapter-installed